# Fetching data from Fragements - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `ViewPager` which holds some 5-6 fragments. The fragments contains different input fields. So I want to fetch the data from all the fragments on an event, say button click.

What I have in my mind is I can send data from the fragment to the activity via `onPause` and for the fragment(s) that are not destroyed, I can call some fragment's function that will get the data and return.

What is the best / correct way to do it? More specifically, what to do when the fragment's view is destroyed? Thank you.

```
class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    .........

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ......
        ViewPager pager = .....
        pager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        ...........
    }
}
class MyAadapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    public MyAadapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment= null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment=new FragOne();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment=new FragTwo();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment=new FragThree();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment=new FragFour();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Button click on which you want to get data from fragments is a part of the fragment or an activity?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Activity

Comment: So you can do it by implementing Inteface

Comment: post your code so that I can tell you where and how you can implementing it

Comment: Added code. Fragment's code is usual.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia hey, need more info?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52456/discussion-between-emotionull-and-biraj-zalavadia)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that view pager is your best solution as you can swipe between fragments without enter any data.

I would suggest you to make your own flow, show fragment A - if user enters data add some button next to fragment B and pass bundle with the data etc..etc.. until last fragment.

In the last fragment add the button Finish (for example) and than pass all the information it to the activity with callback.